# Tkinter Screen Not Centered

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

When I run the code the box appears in the top left, with most out of the view of the screen. I have gone over the code and cannot find what it causing this. Thanks for any help.

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3 
import LoginMenu

class LogOn:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window
        window.title("Log On")
        window.state("zoomed")

        h = self.window.winfo_height()
        w = self.window.winfo_width()
        Center_h = h/2
        Center_w = w/2


        self.FrameLogOn = Frame(window, bg = "PaleTurquoise1")
        self.FrameLogOn.place(x = Center_w , y = Center_h, anchor = "center")

        self.lbl_TrainerID = Label(self.FrameLogOn, text = "TrainerID:", bg = "PaleTurquoise1", font =("Arial","16"), width = 15)
        self.lbl_TrainerID.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.ent_TrainerID = Entry(self.FrameLogOn, bg = "PaleTurquoise1", font =("Arial","16"))
        self.ent_TrainerID.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        self.lbl_TrainerIDError = Label(self.FrameLogOn, text = "*TrainerID Not Found" ,bg = "PaleTurquoise1", font =("Arial","16"), fg = "PaleTurquoise1",  width = 15)
        self.lbl_TrainerIDError.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

        self.lbl_Password = Label(self.FrameLogOn, text = "Password:" ,bg = "PaleTurquoise1", font =("Arial","16"),  width = 15)
        self.lbl_Password.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        self.ent_Password = Entry(self.FrameLogOn, bg = "PaleTurquoise1", font =("Arial","16"))
        self.ent_Password.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        self.lbl_PasswordError = Label(self.FrameLogOn, text = "*Incorrect Password" ,bg = "PaleTurquoise1", font =("Arial","16"), fg = "PaleTurquoise1",  width = 15)
        self.lbl_PasswordError.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

        self.btn_LogIn = Button(self.FrameLogOn, text = "Log In", bg = "PaleTurquoise1", font =("Arial", "16"),  width = 15, command = self.LogIn)
        self.btn_LogIn.grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 3)
```

Comment: can you explain which widget is at top left

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] for the specific issue you're having, as opposed to a class in some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `place` which is a bit complex, how about using pack? As I understand this is what you want:

```
self.FrameLogOn = Frame(window, bg = "PaleTurquoise1")
self.FrameLogOn.pack(expand=True)
```

Just replace

```
h = self.window.winfo_height()
w = self.window.winfo_width()

Center_h = h/2
Center_w = w/2
self.FrameLogOn.place(x = Center_w , y = Center_h, anchor = "center")
```

with `self.FrameLogOn.pack(expand=True)`.

`expand=True` option will keep inner frame in the center of the window.

Answer (score 0):

Your window isn't managed by a geometry manager yet and therefore `winfo_width()` and `winfo_height()` will return 1. If you add `window.update_idletasks()` before `h = self.window.winfo_height()` then the problem is solved. So like this:

```
window.state("zoomed")
window.update_idletasks()
h = self.window.winfo_height()
```

Answer (score 0):

`place` lets you use relative coordinates. `relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="center"` places a widget exactly in the middle of its master.